# Why does a build of a qmake project fail with 'qglobal.h': No such file or directory?

Tags: qt, qmake

I'm trying to release-build a qmake-based, Qt-using project (Qt Creator) as follows, starting from a clean command prompt:

```
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86
cd build
\qt\5.7.0-shared\bin\qmake.exe "CONFIG=release" \qt\qt-creator-opensource-src-4.1.0
nmake
```

Output:

```
[...]fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'qglobal.h': No such file or directory
```

This is perfectly reproducible on every machine I've tried it on, across multiple Qt versions. The choice of a project doesn't matter: it could be a trivial one.

Comment: While the problem definitely **is** a typo, it is a typo that could send one (ekhm) on a wild goose chase.

Answer (score 1):

The `CONFIG` qmake variable holds a list of default values. One of those is `QT`. By assigning to it, the defaults are overriden. Thus `QT` is removed from the configuration, and the build does not to depend on Qt. Thus no Qt includes are found.

Instead, one must *append* the value to `CONFIG`:

```
qmake "CONFIG+=release" [...]
```